# How to keep memory of process protected

Tags: c#, windows, memory

I have a process that will have some important values in the memory. I don't want anyone to be able to read the memory of my process and obtain those values. So I tried to create a program that would look at the list of programs running and determine if any of them were "debuggers", etc. But I realized that someone could just write a quick program to dump the memory of my process. I know several process on my system have their memory protected. How could I also obtain this? (ps: I'm using C#)

Comment: You may use this class to secure strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Any* application that runs under an user with enough privileged (eg. local administrator) can call [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx) and read your process at will, any time, without being attached to your process debugging port, and without your processing being able to prevent, or even detect this. And I'm not even going into what is possible for a system kernel driver to do...

Ultimately, all solutions available to do this are either snake oil, or just a way to obfuscate the problem by raising the bar to make it harder. Some do make it really hard, but none make it bullet-proof. But ultimately, one cannot hide anything from a user that has physical access to the machine and has sufficiently elevated privileges.

If you don't want users to read something, simply don't have on the user machine. Use a service model where your IP is on a server and users access it via internet (ie. web services).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there will always be a way to dump the memory image of your program. Your program can only make it harder, never impossible. That said, there may be ways to 'hide' the values. It is generally considered hard to do and not worth the trouble, but there are programs which encrypt those values in memory. However, to be able to use them, they need to decrypt them temporarily and re-encrypt (or discard) them afterwards.

While encryption is easy with the .Net framework, discarding the decrypted value is not an easy thing to do in C#. In C, you would allocate a chunk of memory to store the decrypted values and clear that (by writing zero's or random data to it) before freeing it. In C#, there is no guarantee that your data won't be stored somewhere (caching, garbage collection) and you won't be able to clear it. However, as eulerfx noted in a comment, in .Net 4.0 [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) may be used. How safe that is, I don't know.

As you may see, there will always be a short time where the value lies in memory unencrypted, and that is the vulnerability here.

Comment: I have not doubt that a expert hacker could get at it. I just want to make sure that all the novices cant.

Comment: @Lienau: the problem with expert vs. novice is that is enough for *one* expert to hack it, and then all the novices will find on Google how to do it. Only a few individuals understand how to jailbreak an iPhone from scratch, but *many* an iPhones are jailbreaked. If the price is worth it, someone will do it.

Comment: In that case, you could write a wrapper for SecureString which appends the bytes of the value you want to store as chars to the SecureString instance. SecureString provides the encryption, and your wrapper decodes the chars back to bytes (or any other type) when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is employ a commercial solution such as in this [PDF brochure](http://www.softwaremag.com/trk.cfm?uid=74), this is their [website](http://www.arxan.com/). You may be better off going down this route if you really care about protecting the application from sniffing, IP theft etc instead of rolling up your own solution...

**Edit:** *I would not go down the route in kidding myself that the solution I shall craft up will be tamper proof, crack proof, idiot proof*. Leave that to a company like Arxan I mentioned (I aint a sales rep - I'm just giving an example), sure it might be costly, but you can sleep better at night knowing it is **much harder** for a cracker to break than having ***no solution*** at all...